# How to focus the next input with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, wordle-game

I'm creating a game like wordle and, to do this, when the user writes a letter, the app should focus the next input. I can't do this, and I don't know why.

```
    
const GameLine = (props) => {

    const lineIndex = props.index;
  
    const checkTry = () => {
        const userGuess = firstLetter + ' ' + secondLetter + ' ' + thirdLetter + ' ' + fourthLetter + ' ' + fifthLetter;
        console.log(userGuess);
    }

    const [firstLetter, setFirstLetter] = useState(null);
    const [secondLetter, setSecondLetter] = useState(null);
    const [thirdLetter, setThirdLetter] = useState(null);
    const [fourthLetter, setFourthLetter] = useState(null);
    const [fifthLetter, setFifthLetter] = useState(null);
  
    const handleNextInput = (e) => {
        console.log("ID atual: " + e.target.id);
        const fieldName = e.target.id.split('-')[1];
        const nextSibiling = document.getElementById(`box${lineIndex}-${parseInt(fieldName) + 1}`);
        console.log(nextSibiling);
        if(nextSibiling !== null){
            nextSibiling.focus();
        }
    }


    return ( 
        <BoxesDiv>
            <Box1 type="text" id={ `box${lineIndex}-1`} onChange={(e) => { handleNextInput(e); setFirstLetter(e.target.value)}} value={firstLetter} /> 
            <Box2 type="text" id={ `box${lineIndex}-2`} onChange={(e) => setSecondLetter(e.target.value)} value={secondLetter} onKeyPress={(e)=>handleNextInput(e)}/>
            <Box3 type="text" id={ `box${lineIndex}-3`} onChange={(e) => { handleNextInput(e); setThirdLetter(e.target.value)}} value={thirdLetter} /> 
            <Box4 type="text" id={ `box${lineIndex}-4`} onChange={(e) => { handleNextInput(e); setFourthLetter(e.target.value)}} value={fourthLetter} />
            <Box5 type="text" id={ `box${lineIndex}-5`} onChange={(e) => setFifthLetter(e.target.value)} value={fifthLetter} onKeyPress={ (e)=>{ if(e.key === "Enter"){checkTry()} } }/>
        </BoxesDiv>  
    );
}
```

I'm trying to get the next input with id and use Element.focus(), but nothing happens. Could someone help me to find where's my error?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

React's way of accessing elements is to use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref). You can create an array of refs initially and map them to the inputs. Add a `keyup` event listener to update the input focus to the next input.

Try like below.

```
import { useState, createRef, useEffect } from "react";

const GameLine = (props) => {
  const lineIndex = props.index;
  // number of inputs
  const numerOfInputs = props?.numerOfInputs || 5;

  // create a array of refs
  const [inputRefsArray] = useState(() =>
    Array.from({ length: numerOfInputs }, () => createRef())
  );

  // state for current input index
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  // save letters in a array where each entry in the array refers to an input
  const [letters, setLetters] = useState(() =>
    Array.from({ length: numerOfInputs }, () => "")
  );

  const handleKeyPress = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => {
      // calculate the next input index, next input after the final input will be again the first input. you can change the logic here as per your needs
      const nextIndex = prevIndex < numerOfInputs - 1 ? prevIndex + 1 : 0;
      const nextInput = inputRefsArray?.[nextIndex]?.current;
      nextInput.focus();
      nextInput.select();
      return nextIndex;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // focus the firs iput initially
    if (inputRefsArray?.[0]?.current) {
      inputRefsArray?.[0]?.current?.focus();
    }
    
    // add the event listener for keyup keyboard event
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyPress, false);
    
    // remove the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {inputRefsArray.map((ref, index) => {
        return (
          <input
            ref={ref}
            type="text"
            id={`box${index}-1`}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const { value } = e.target;
              setLetters((letters) =>
                letters.map((letter, letterIndex) =>
                  letterIndex === index ? value : letter
                )
              );
            }}
            onClick={(e) => {
              setCurrentIndex(index);
              e.target.select();
            }}
            value={letters[index]}
            max={"1"}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameLine;
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-franklin-m94ci0]

Answer (score 1):

You should called **handleNextInput** function for second box. I think you could onKeyUp function for **handleNextInput**.

```
<Box2 onKeyUp={(e)=>handleNextInput(e)} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a function that checks if the user pressed the enter key.
If yes, you will get the index of the first element in the form. and then focusing on the element that have (index + 2).
Because the first TextField has  index =0 and the second TextField has the index = 2

```
    function handleEnter(event){
                        console.log(event.key)
                        if (event.key === "Enter") {
                            const form = event.target.form;
                            const index = [...form].indexOf(event.target);
                            console.log(index)
                            form[index + 2].focus();
                            event.preventDefault();
                          }
                    }
            
            
    <form>
            
 <TextField onKeyDown={(e)=>handleEnter(e)} variant="outlined" label='name' />
 <TextField onKeyDown={(e)=>handleEnter(e)} variant="outlined" label='age' />
                    
 <Buttontype='submit' variant="contained" >Ajouter le client</Button>
                       
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason you don't have access to the `event`, you can do this:

```
const someMethodWithoutAccessToEvent = () => {
  const active = document.activeElement;
  if (active?.nextElementSibling) {
    (active.nextElementSibling as HTMLElement).focus();
  }
}
```

Works like charm

Comment: Dosnt work if the elements are in different parents

Answer (score 0):

I use the input id, and the document for set the focus

```
document.getElementById('txt0').focus();
```

If you have dynamic fields you cand add a dynamic id. Example:

```
                {arrayItems.map((item, index) => {
                        <TextField
                          id={'txt' + index}
                          onKeyUp={(event) => {
                            if (event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
                              document.getElementById(`txt`+(index+1)).focus();
                            }
                            if (event.key == 'ArrowUp' && index > 0) {
                              document.getElementById(`txt`+(index-1)).focus();
                            }
                          }}
                        />
                }
```